# Is there a ppa for gcc4.7?

Tags: 11.10, ppa, gcc

Are there any good ppa's for gcc4.7 and the required libstdc++?
Perferably for ubuntu 11.10, Any links are appreciated!

Comment: for which version of ubuntu?

Comment: @fossfreedom, edited original question.

Comment: Please mark an answer if correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No PPA needed. There's [gcc-snapshot](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/gcc-snapshot) package in `universe`. That include libstdc++ and everything else, but all installed under `/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot`.

Of course, it's only 4.7 until 4.8 development starts in a few months time, at which point I'd expect there to be a gcc-4.7 package, although I don't know for sure.